# Getting text from title attribute of element while appending to it

Tags: jquery, dom, dom-manipulation

I have function which append div (help icon) after all element with `.help` class.

```
jQuery().ready(function() {
     jQuery('.help').append('<div class="mark"></div>');
});
```

What do I need to add to that function to get information from title attribute of `.help` element?

I'm new in scripting.

Comment: Do you need to GET or SET information to the "title" attribute of each element with a "help" class?

Comment: Take a look at the `each` method in the jQuery API documentation (http://api.jquery.com/each/).

Comment: i dont really understand your question. can you tell more aboute your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilizing the fact that [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) can also accept a function that will create the HTML string to append:

```
$('.help').append(function () {
    return '<div class="mark" title="' + $(this).attr('title') + '"></div>';
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:

```
jQuery().ready(function() {
jQuery('.help').each( function(index, elem){
    $(this).append('<div class="mark" title="' + $(this).attr("title") + '"></div>')
});
```

});

Comment: yes @johnhunter, I was happy to post my (first ever) answer, just to see somebody else was doing the same, in the same minute :)

Answer (score 1):

I *think* you are looking for something like this:

```
jQuery().ready(function() {

    // with each help element....
    jQuery('.help').each(function () {

        // create the empty mark, add the title from help, append mark to help
        $('<div class="mark"></div>').attr('title', $(this).attr('title')).appendTo(this);
    });
});
```

This will add a `div.mark` to each help element and set the title of the mark to be the title of the parent help.

Comment: @ctekse - we're thinking along the same lines :)

Comment: GREAT this is what i'm lookin' for to :]

Answer (score 0):

```
var title = $('.help').attr("title");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var title = jQuery('.help').attr('title');

jQuery('.mark').attr('title',title);
```

Comment: GREAT this is what i'm lookin' for

Answer (score -1):

Try to use the [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) function:

```
jQuery().ready(function() { 
    console.log( jQuery('.help').attr( 'title' ) );
});
```